# Getting the information from the Response tab in dev tools with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I need to get the response of a site after I've submitted a form.
For example my form's action points to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) and when I submit the form I need to get the
response information that happens from it (the details that show up in the Response tab under Network.

I've tried this in my controller

```
$response = Http::post('http://www.example.com/', [
    'name' => 'Steve'
]);
```

But I don't get any of the information that you get in the Response tab

Answer (score 1):

Your controller code is server sided.

The network tab in devtools is clients sided.

The HTTP facade returns the response, using of the following methods you may do something with the response

```php
$response->body() : string;
$response->json() : array|mixed;
$response->status() : int;
$response->ok() : bool;
$response->successful() : bool;
$response->failed() : bool;
$response->serverError() : bool;
$response->clientError() : bool;
$response->header($header) : string;
$response->headers() : array;
```

See the following link to the docs for more info
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#making-requests